# Unit test RedisCacheModule Nestjs

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, redis, jestjs, nestjs

I have this module **redisCache.module.ts**

```js
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisCacheService } from '../services/redisCache.service';
import { config } from '../../config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: async () => {
        return {
          store: redisStore,
          host: config.redisHost,
          port: config.redisPort,
          auth_pass: config.redisPass,
          ttl: config.redisTTL,
          tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          },
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RedisCacheService],
  exports: [RedisCacheService],
})
export class RedisCacheModule {}
```

In my code coverage I get the following
[image]

Looks like the **useFactory** and the **return {...}** lines are not being tested.

I have attempted to create the following test **redisCache.module.spec.ts**

```js
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { RedisCacheModule } from './redisCache.module';

describe('RedisCacheModule', () => {
  let sut: RedisCacheModule;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [RedisCacheModule, CacheModule],
    }).compile();
    sut = module.get<RedisCacheModule>(RedisCacheModule);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(sut).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should call registerAsync', () => {
    expect(jest.spyOn(CacheModule, 'registerAsync')).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But the second test fails. It looks like registerAsync is never called:
[image]

How can I unit test these lines successfully?

Comment: `CacheModule` isn't provider. Thus, you shouldn't add it to the `providers` list

Comment: you don't need to write unit tests for modules, btw. There's no unit to test in there. They are handled by nestjs. Somehow I've mangaged to cover those `.module.ts` files just by writing unit tests for `.service.ts` ones. Use this repo as an exemple: https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs

Comment: My redisCache.service.ts is 100% tested, and it is mocking the CacheManager, so it never actually uses the Redis cache, and therefore these missing lines are never covered. I don't know how I can cover them without changing that, but I don't think I should access the real Redis on Unit tests. Hence my question. Whether the test resides on a .module.spec.ts or .service.spec.ts, either way is fine for me. I just want to understand how I can do it.